# destructuring from module imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a index.js in a folder called "vuex" with the following

```
const module = { state, mutations, actions, getters }

export default { module, plugin }
```

state, mutations, actions were imported from another file

I'm trying to get the "state" property in another file so I

```
import module from './veux'
```

then

```
const { state } = module
```

however `state` is **undefined** which is weird because `console.log(module)` shows me that `module.state` is present

I'm  new to this ES6-7 flow so but what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have exported the object `{module, plugin}` as `default export`

after importing like

```
import module from './veux'
```

module will have structure like

```
module = {
    module: { state, mutations, actions, getters },
    plugin
}
```

so in order to access state, you will write `module.module.state` or

```
const {module: {state}} = module; // nested destructuring
console.log(state)
```

an easier to understand and readable method would be to export your module with named export like

```
export const module = { state, mutations, actions, getters }

export default plugin
```

and import it like

```
import plugin, { module } from './veux'
```

after which you can do

```
const { state } = module;
```

Comment: ooohhhhhh so can't I deconstruct it further? or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to get the "state" property in another file so I
>
> ```
> import module from './veux'
> const { state } = module
> ```
>
> however state is undefined which is weird because console.log(module)
>   shows me that module.state is present

No, you're importing the whole default-exported object (with its `module` and `plugin` properties) as `module`. The property would be `module.module.state`.

> I have a index.js in a folder called "vuex" with the following
>
> ```
> const module = { state, mutations, actions, getters }
> export default { module, plugin }
> ```

Don't. Use named exports for exporting multiple things:

```
export const module = { state, mutations, actions, getters }
export { plugin }
```

then you can do

```
import { module } from './veux'
const { state } = module
```

Answer (score -1):

It'll work if you do this:

```
import { module } from './veux';
```